# fetching data from a table recursively

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sybase

I need to fetch data from table in recursive manner.
The data would be like 
there will be a parent and it has number of childs in it.
the structure of the data is like a tree but each node having multiple childs.

the table structure is like :

```
Description----column name
--------------------------
key of the item---key
parent of the item----parent
```

I can get the key of the root from another table as below:

```
select key from BSC where name="0201".
```

using this key i need to fetch all the children till the leaves of this tree.

the only input i have is the name of the item.
if i want the children of the root i can fetch it using:

```
select bpkey from MYTABLE where parent in (select bpkey from BSC where name="0201")
```

But this is just the children of the root.i need to fetch the children of children and children...and it goes on.

But i need to fetch all the keys in that tree.

I am not that much good at writing sql queries.
Probably i think we need to go for recursion here and a stored procedure.

Could anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a temp table to hold the result of hierarchy.

```
create table #temp2(id int, parentid int null)
```

Insert the only record from which you expect the hierarchy result.

```
declare loop cursor
   for select * from #temp2
go

declare @id int
declare @parentid int

open loop
fetch loop
    into @id, @parentid
while(@@sqlstatus = 0)
begin 

insert into #temp2
select id,parentid from #temp1 where parentid=@id

fetch loop
    into @id, @parentid
end
close loop
DEALLOCATE cursor loop
```

The above query also has an assumption of source table as `#temp1` and the result table as `#temp2`

Comment: I dont have a table to hold the result.

Comment: you could use temp tables like I have used. It will created and used only for a db session. `create table #temp2(id int, parentid int null)`

Comment: This is nothing but `BFS` with temp table as a `queue` to track the visited nodes in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Sybase supports common table expressions (ie: sql anywhere )

```
;with cte as
(
    select [key], parent from yourtable
    union all
    select t1.[key], t2.parent from yourtable t1
    inner join cte t2 on t1.parent=t2.[key]
)
    select * from cte where parent= [parent to search for]
```